# Three.js error "camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera" when trying to render a cube

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a little "engine" of sorts that allows me to easily create and position objects using three.js. So far I am able to set up a scene, renderer, and camera and everything seems to be working properly, until I try to render and attach a cube to my scene.

I am able to create the cube and attach it to my scene just fine, but my code seems to fail when I try to use the render() function in three.js and I get the error:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera.
```

But I'm not really sure why. I can't find much about this error online so I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.

While troubleshooting, I tried to output my cube to the console to see if I could get any useful info from it. It seems like it attaches to my scene just fine and both my scene and camera show up as a parent object to the cube.

Here's the code:

```
function spnScene(alias, fov, x, y, z) {
    window.spnCreateScene = new THREE.Scene();
    var WIDTH = window.innerWidth, HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    if (alias == false) {
        console.warn('spnRenderer scene antialias set to ' + alias + ". Please check your code to make sure it's correct.");
    }

    spnRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: alias
    });
    spnRenderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    document.body.appendChild(spnRenderer.domElement);

    // create camera

    spnCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 2000);
    spnCamera.position.set(x, y, z);
    spnCreateScene.add(spnCamera);
}

function spnBasicCube(material, clr, l, w, depth, x, y, z) { // draw a basic cube and render it
    if (material == "basic") {
        var spnBasicCube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(l, w, depth), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: clr}));
        spnBasicCube.position.x = x;
        spnBasicCube.position.y = y;
        spnBasicCube.position.z = z;
        spnCreateScene.add(spnBasicCube);

        spnRenderer.render(spnBasicCube);

        console.log(spnBasicCube);

        // this should end up making a cube but throws an error rn
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't render the cube

<s>`spnRenderer.render(spnBasicCube);`</s>

but render the scene with the camera:

```js
spnRenderer.render(spnCreateScene, spnCamera);
```

See the documentation [`THREE.WebGLRenderer.render`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.render):

> ```
> .render ( scene : Scene, camera : Camera ) : null
> ```
>
> Render a scene using a camera.